# PHP - Paypal payment transaction

Tags: php, paypal

I've a problem with Paypal IPN. The callback works very well.

I've a site and anyone can signup for free in my site. Later, the user can upgrade the account and here intervenes paypal.

How can I be sure that the user (A) paid to the transaction_id (0123) ?

Ex.

User (A) -> Click to button (item_number = (0009)) -> redirect to paypal page;

User (?) paid -> Paypal IPN sended and server received data -> [Which user has paid?]

!! This, without the user return to the site !!

Thank You

Comment: parse the user id to paypal and you will get it back inthe IPN

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. I don't know the user info. I thought about doing this:

Create a random string and save it in the database with the user ID. I enter this string in item_number and when I receive the IPN I know the account ID. But it could easily be hack, because bassta replace the string with that of another user.

Comment: so a person would replace the string, and therefore pay for someone else- do you think that's likely? There's no benefit in any one faking who paid in this situation. no need for random string the id is fine

Comment: You're right ;) but there is no other way to connect the paypal transaction with site account? If there isn't, just say no :) Thank you

Comment: a.) Dont use Paypal-IPN (if you have no experience, the requests can be hacked - You can fake transactions), use **Paypal PDT**, b.) Use custom variables to assign transactions to users: https://www.google.de/search?q=paypal+IPN+custom+variables

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry @Vincenzo Raco, but that is bad advice.

PDT and IPN are essentially the same exact thing except that PDT sends data to your return URL and IPN sends it to a silent listener.

There is no guarantee that users will make it back to your return URL, even if you have Auto Return enabled, so it's never a good idea to handle post-payment processing tasks on the return URL. If your IPN is getting hacked that means you have a problem with your configuration.

All IPN's are verified with PayPal's servers, and if you're using API calls, hosted buttons, encrypted buttons, etc. people can't see the original code, copy it, and make adjustments to pricing, which would be the only potential "hack" that anybody could do.  Just make sure not to use basic, standard HTML buttons and that potential problem goes away.

IPN is definitely what you want to use to handle your post-payment processing.  You can save your user record or whatever data you're working with in your database prior to sending the user over to PayPal.  You can include the record ID of your database in the PayPal payment request (I typically use the invoice parameter for this) and then that will be returned in IPN so that you can pull that data back out of your database or add new related accordingly.

Comment: I read a lot, and You're right: PDT and IPN are the same thing, but PDT sends data always once, instead IPN resends a confirmation until your site acknowledges receipt. PDT it's for in-app purchases (for example) - So, I've these big problems:

1. Recognize the person who paid. User A, B or C? How to do? - as I wrote above, I think a solution: generate random string and save into DB with user_id. Insert the string, into item_number field. The user click, pay and I receive IPN and execute the script. Is it good idea?
2. Check the values ​​before you pay. For IPN it's late /the payment has gone

Comment: Is there a documentation for encrypt data? I search on the web and paypal documentation, but i didn't found this. I know that there is, but where?

Comment: IPN will only resend if your script fails and doesn't send a successful response back to their server.  If that's happening then you've got a problem with your script that needs to be fixed.  Payer status, address status, seller protection eligibility, etc. are all returned in the IPN details so you can verify who paid and anything you feel like you might need to in order to automate procedures as necessary.

Comment: Check this:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/